# Need help using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I want to make the password label and text field below the ID..but i`m kind of new to GriBagLayout.

I hope you can help me.

Here is my code:

```
   class LoginPanel extends JPanel {//login components
        private JButton exitbtn = new JButton("Exit");
        private JLabel idLabel = new JLabel("Staff ID : ");
        private JTextField idJtf = new JTextField(10);
        private JLabel pwLabel = new JLabel("Password : ");
        private JPasswordField pwJtf = new JPasswordField(10);
        LoginPanel() {
           setOpaque(false);
           setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
           setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
           //add(new JLabel("Staff ID: ")); add(new JTextField(10));
           //add(new JLabel("Password: ")); add(new JPasswordField(10));
           add(idLabel);
           add(idJtf);
           add(pwLabel);
           add(pwJtf);
           //add(exitbtn);
        }      
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is as simple as just reading [this tutorial: GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you are familiar with creating HTML pages using tables, GridBagLayout should be easy for you

Placing controls one below the other is like placing them to a table with single column. It means that you need to set 0 as a column number and [0..3] as row numbers:

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
int rowNum = 0
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = rowNum;
add(idLabel, c);

c.gridy++;
add(idJtf, c);

c.gridy++;
add(pwLabel, c);

c.gridy++;
add(pwJtf, c);
```

However for such simple layout you can use another layout managers

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and stop using GridBagLayout. GridBagLayout is a layoutmanager from a previous era. I'll realize it is in all the "official" Oracle Java docs but most people avoid it now a days (and for good reasons). A good alternative for complex layouts GridBag is meant to tackle is Jgoodies FormLayout ( http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/ ). I'll guarantee you that you will maintain your sanity and your life's quality will improve measurably :-)